# How to I get php.ini to show error message

Tags: php

I've looked for solutions to show error on my local php website, but beside setting display_errors through 
`ini_set('display_errors','1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`
or through .htaccess file, I can't make my website to show error. Although it seems that my default setting of `display_errors` has no problem at all.
Is there anyone could help me with this? Or I just have to save a `.htaccess` file every time I try to run something.

Apparently I'm still pretty new to PHP, and that's part of the reason I really try to know what's going on here and save myself some time while I'm learning many ideas and function of PHP.

many thanks!

part of my php.ini and this is the right version php.ini file that my server loads.

I think this is the part of php.ini file I should edit.

Working on to test the result!

```
; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; For production environments, we recommend logging errors rather than
; sending them to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the actual contents of your INI file. The sections you included in your question come way before the actual setting of the values in the example INI files that are supplied with PHP.

Comment: There might be multiple `php.ini` files on your system, make sure you edit the right one. Use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on a page to see if your edits are valid. Also, restart your webserver after making changes

Comment: @Dave and  kerbholz, thank you both. I indeed didn't edit the right part of the code in php.ini, and probably didn't get the right version php.ini in the first hand.
Thanks a lot for your reminder.
Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I didn't get edit the right part of the code in the first hand.